# Implement Multiple Models in Different Servers On Single View

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sql-server-2008-r2, asp.net-mvc-5

Good Morning,

First, my environment:

- VS 2013
- ASP.NET MVC5
- EF5 (forcibly because VS wouldn't let me choose EF6)
- Plant A data is on SQL Server in Server A contains DB_A
- Plant B data is on SQL Server in Server B contains DB_B

I am creating a page where we display production data coming from SCADA system. So, I thought maybe an asp.net mvc w/ bootstrap carousel would blow the bosses' minds. I tried [this](http://www.thingswelearned.com/Article/Details/33539758-547f-4a2e-b958-83f6e2fa1a25) example and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/Multiple-Models-in-a-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-MVC) one too complementing with ASP.NET MVC 5 Database First tutorial.
The DBs are the same, except for taking in info from different plants, eg. DB name is same, column names are same.

When I create model A, it shows the model.cs for my DBA under model A edmx, but when I create model B, it shows only under model B edmx.

My problem starts when I need to join both models to use on the view. Both examples show different models yes but on the same database; mine are in different servers.

How can I go about this?

Poluskinha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the databases are the same you can use the same model to house them (one edmx file). You can dictate where your data is coming from by simply using the appropriate connection string.

What I would do is create a repository layer that can query both databases and then return things like a single list containing all the products from both plants.

With the repository layer managing your data access you can now treat the MVC part of your app just as any other app that uses a single server.

One issue you will have to think about is the fact that identical tables are going to have ID collisions. If you're planning on doing anything more than reads of this data you're going to have to reconcile this.

Comment: Hi again, thank you for your response Shoe. I took long because I wanted to try all the possibilities. Good news is, I found a DB_B on the same server as DB_A, and the table name was tableB (therefore different names). Adding the models worked out fine. I can have a view for each of the models. Now come the joining part to get the carousel working for them. I am going to redo the examples I gave above, they have repository layer. Will give feedback on how it goes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was taking from a DB that is not being "used", although it's updated with plant information. I found another DB with a different name and it was okay.

Tweaking the Multiple Models with View Model example, I added 2 edmx, one for each model, and lucky me, the column names came out different.
So I just created a class called Repository with two methods, one for each model, to return the latest production information.

After that, created a folder called ViewModels, a class called ViewModel inside that folder and add getters and setters for each model.

It's MVC, so I used the existing Index.cshtml and added the ViewModel class as the model, the DisplayFor was like this:

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.latestA.[tagnameA]) --> for model A data

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.latestB.[tagnameB) --> for model B data

A bit of bootstrap carousel to make it pretty and voilá.

Thanks Shoe for the Repository thing, I didn't understand at first, and it gave me inspiration to do more research.